# Is there any way I can set my large categories list on header two show in 2 columns?

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu, categories

I have a long list of categories,  which is appearing on menu drop down almost the mid of home page, that's why I want to convert them in 2 columns, when clicking on menu , the categories should show in 2 columns but at same time.

I am expecting someone to help me how to make it in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to create 2 column HTML categories.

```css
.left-hand-col1{padding-top:1px;width:382px;margin-left:5px;margin-bottom:10px;}
#categories1{padding-right:5px;margin-right:15px}
#categories-list1,#popular-list1{list-style-type:none;padding:0;margin:0}
#categories-list1 li{float:left}
#categories-list1 li a,#popular-list1 li a{border-bottom:solid 1px #e3e8ea;display:block;width:170px;color:#28AF1B;text-decoration:none;padding:1px 0 1px}
#categories-list1 li a:hover,#popular-list1 li a:hover{color:#212121;text-decoration:underline}
```

```html
<div class='left-hand-col1'>
<div id='categories1'><h2>Categories</h2>
<ul id='categories-list1'>
<li><a href='#' title='Category 1'>Category 1</a></li>
<li><a href='#' title='Category 2'>Category 2</a></li>
<li><a href='#' title='Category 3'>Category 3</a></li>
<li><a href='#' title='Category 4'>Category 4</a></li>
<li><a href='#' title='Category 5'>Category 5</a></li>
<li><a href='#' title='Category 6'>Category 6</a></li>
<li><a href='#' title='Category 7'>Category 7</a></li>
<li><a href='#' title='Category 8'>Category 8</a></li>
<li><a href='#' title='Category 9'>Category 9</a></li>
<li><a href='#' title='Category 10'>Category 10</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```